# How to exclude a MW2 Map Pack to a PS3 account?

Tags: ps3, call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2

My son downloaded a Map Pack for Modern Warfare II on PS3 with his account.

When I play to MW2 with my account, I don't want to play into these maps.

Is it possible to exclude these maps from my account and not to my son's account ?

We have two different PSN identifiers.

---

EDIT
If I join session with someone that haven't downloaded the Map Pack, it's desactivated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a DLC is installed in a machine, it'll be available for all accounts on that machine automatically until the master account (the account that downloaded these DLCs) is deleted or deactivated.

So your best bet is to "De-activate" his account when you want to play, this will block the DLCs and when he wants to play he can re-activate it...BUT be aware that de-activating and re-activating an account **MAY**  cause a problem (even though it has never caused any problems to me) so I would better contact Sony and ask them about that.